# Action Plans V3 Unmanaged - Unable to undelete Accounts

Tags: action, undelete

I've been using "Action Plans V3 Unmanaged" for years.  However we just tried to undelete an account and found that "Action Plans V3" is blocking the undelete.  The error I get is this:

```
Unable to undelete 1 of the record(s) because:

The record may have already been undeleted or removed from the Recycle Bin
The record may have been orphaned by the deletion of the custom object
You may no longer have access to undelete the record(s)
A data integrity rule or Apex trigger would fail if the record was undeleted
```

If I disable the trigger that came bundled with "Action Plans V3", I can undelete an account without any issues.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Here's what the trigger code looks like:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before delete, after undelete) {

    set<ID>             aIds    = new set<ID>();
    List<String>        apIds   = new List<String>();
    List<ActionPlan__c> deletePermantently_apIds= new List<ActionPlan__c>();

    //Delete related action plans
    if ( trigger.isdelete ){
        for( Account a : trigger.old ){
            aIds.add( a.Id );
        }

        /* GET Action Plans to delete from recycle bin */
        deletePermantently_apIds = [ select Id, Name , LastModifiedDate from ActionPlan__c where Account__c in : aIds and isDeleted = true ALL ROWS ];

        if ( deletePermantently_apIds.size() >0 ){          
            Database.emptyRecycleBin(deletePermantently_apIds);
        }

        //Get all action plans associated with Accounts
        for( Account a : [Select (Select Id , isDeleted From Action_Plans__r) From Account a where Id in : aIds]){
            if (a.Action_Plans__r.size() >0 ){
                for(ActionPlan__c ap :a.Action_Plans__r ){                  
                    apIds.add(ap.Id);
                }
            }
        }
        if ( apIds.size() >0 ){     
            ActionPlansBatchDelete aPBatch = new ActionPlansBatchDelete(apIds, Userinfo.getUserId());
            Database.ExecuteBatch( aPBatch );
        }
    }

    //Undelete related action plans
    if ( trigger.isUnDelete ){
        Database.UndeleteResult[] unDel_errors;
        for( Account a : trigger.new ){
            aIds.add( a.Id );
        }
        list <ActionPlan__c> aPs = [ select Id, Name , LastModifiedDate from ActionPlan__c where Account__c in : aIds and isDeleted = true ALL ROWS ];

        try{
            if(ActionPlanObjectTriggerTest.isTest){
                //throw dmlException
                insert new Contact();   
            }

            unDel_errors =Database.undelete( aPs,false);
        } catch ( Dmlexception e ){             
            for (Account a: trigger.new){
                a.addError('You can not undelete an action plan whose related object is deleted.');
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all clear to me why Action Plans sees fit to block an undelete simply because it cannot itself undelete a related Action Plan, which is what it's doing.

If you don't want to spend your time debugging Action Plans to find out why it fails to perform its own undelete, and can live with your undeleted Accounts not getting their Action Plans back if an error occurs, you can simply comment out these lines:

```
        for (Account a: trigger.new){
            a.addError('You can not undelete an action plan whose related object is deleted.');
        }
```

in your sandbox, and then use a change set to migrate the updated trigger and its related test class(es) to your production instance.